# Disable logging for one container in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a web application launched using Docker compose that I want to disable all logging for (or at the very least print it out to syslog instead of a file).

When my web application works it can quickly generate an 11GB log file on startup so this eats up my disk space very fast.

I'm aware that normal docker has [logging options](https://www.sumologic.com/2015/04/16/new-docker-logging-drivers/) for its run command but in Docker Compose I use

> docker-compose up

in the application folder to start my application. How would I enable this functionality in my case? I'm not seeing a specific case anywhere online.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You should be able to use [logging](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#logging) feature. Try to set driver to `none`

```
logging:
    driver: none
```

Full example:

```
services:
  website:
    image: nginx
    logging:
      driver: none
```

In recent versions of docker-compose, if all of the services have disabled logging, docker-compose will act as in detach mode. To force the attached mode you can add a simple silent service like that:

```
services:
  website:
    image: nginx
    logging:
      driver: none

  force-attach:
    image: bash
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: The link to the docs is appreciated, but could you please explain exactly how that option should be used to make a container not write logs? I'm setting the driver to `none` but my postgres container still writes heaps of crap to stdout while my tests are running. Very annoying.

Comment: I update the link. Hopefully it should have all the info now

Comment: I found this solution and used it earlier this year. However the behaviour of docker-compose has now changed and `driver: none` no longer has this effect in the latest docker versions. See [this PR against docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1613) for more details.

Comment: Hi @PhilHaigh thanks for the message. I have not used compose recently. Will need to play around. Interesting that the official docs still kind of points to this solution: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#logging

Comment: I ended up running detached and following the one log I wanted to see. That won't work for the OP though as whenever I follow the logs it starts at the very beginning, meaning that all the logs produced are retained until `docker-compose down`.

Comment: I get what you mean now. I've just tested it and forced the compose to wait by adding:
services:
  wait:
    image: bash
    command: tail -f /dev/null

Comment: @PhilHaigh I've expanded the answer, have a look

Comment: As of September 2021, this will only work if using the `docker-compose` commands (note the hyphen) and won't work if you are using the new compose commands integrated directly into Docker, i.e. `docker compose up` (note that the hyphen has been replaced with a space because it's now referencing a command in Docker as opposed to Docker Compose)

Comment: @Geropellicer THANK YOU! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what was going on.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work at all anymore even with docker-compose.  Anyone got insight? On mac m1

Comment: @Geropellicer what is the correct way of disabling the logs with `docker compose` (with space)?

Comment: It doesn't work anymore I guess, is there any other way?

Comment: The Compose Specification (the current specification, not v1, 2, or 3) documents the [`logging` option for services](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#logging). Doesn't work for me. Suspicious.

Answer (score 36):

For a quick config example, something like

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        logging:
            driver: none
```

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly what is asked, but as of September 2021 (on Compose V2), the `--attach` parameter allows to select the services to listen to.

For example `docker compose up --attach your-service` will only display logs for `your-service`.

Comment: This is very useful, but why is it not documented in https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/ ?

Comment: Pay attention that `--attach` will only run the specified container in the `docker-compose` v1. You should have compose v2 installed for this to work. Please check your compose version by running `docker compose --version`. 
Use [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34591999/2245902) if you want to keep using v1.

Answer (score 3):

As the second option, you may be interested in not fully removing logging (what 'none' value does), but in storing logs of some services in **syslog**, there is the driver for it, for instance:

```
certbot:
  image: certbot/certbot
  restart: unless-stopped
  logging:
    driver: "syslog"
```

Note that the syslog daemon must be running on the host machine. To see the logs use for example: `journalctl -n 100 --no-pager`

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use Kipr's suggestion of `--attach` flag ( e.g. IntelliJ IDEA UX limitations ), you can achieve needed result by editing `docker-compose.yml` file  .

Now with Docker Compose v2 you can remove the version top-level configuration. It enables Compose Specification as Docker Compose "version" (see "Warning" on [the related doc page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/) ). The Specification allows to use [the "attach" configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#attach).

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  website:
    image: nginx
    attach: false
```

Warning: Note that there is no version key here. It is important. Also note that Docker Compose v2 command is docker compose (so please, do NOT use docker-compose command with this file).

Comment: I have not been able to use this option. Every time that I try to use I get a `Additional property attach is not allowed`. Could I get an indication of the Compose version you are running? I am running 
Client: Docker Engine - Community  Version:           23.0.1
Docker Compose version v2.16.0

Comment: by contrast, the `--attach` and also the `--no-attach` flags work just fine.

Comment: This should be the new selected answer

Comment: @largehadroncollider Most probably you have `version: ...` in the top of your `docker-compose.yml`. Please, remove that line and use `docker compose` command (without `-` (hyphen) between `docker` and `compose`)

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this is to create an alias in `~/.bash-aliases` (or `~/.zaliases` on zsh):

```bash
alias up='(docker compose up -d && docker compose logs --since 2s -f) || (docker compose stop)'
```

By using the above `up` alias, now you can use the logger field in service description:

```yaml
services:
    your_service:
        logging:
            driver: none
```

The reason you see the logs `despite driver: none` in yaml and starting with `docker compose`, is because `docker compose up` attaches to the containers being ran, it does not rely on the logging API. But `docker compose logs -f` attaches to the logs, which are not stored when you use the none driver.

If you want to hide warnings about no logs for some services, the following alias could be used:

```bash
alias up='docker compose up -d && (docker compose logs --since 3s -f 2> >(grep -v "Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading"))) || (docker compose stop)'
```

Answer (score -3):

Never disable logging, instead you can set some limitation on your services:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1: 
    image: kong 
    logging: 
          options: 
               max-size: "10m" 
               max-file: "3"
```