# Docker-compose: how to start a container with output supressed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that spins up, among several other, a couchdb container (https://hub.docker.com/r/klaemo/couchdb/); and the couchdb container spews out a lot of output when I do the docker-compose up. Is there a way to suppress that output so I see only other containers' s output?

Maybe

1. I can run the couchdb in daemon mode somehow?

or

2. I can override the default command somehow and redirect output to a tmp file?

I am not sure how to do any of the two, and I want to do that within the compose file itself, not by changing my compose file callup command. Any help?

Here is the minimal compose file:

```
couchdb:
  container_name: couchdb
  image: klaemo/couchdb:2.0.0
  ports:
    - "5984:5984"
```

and I call that from a makefile with : `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --force-recreate && docker-compose down`

Comment: I like this solution for it's simplicity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590317/disable-logging-for-one-container-in-docker-compose

Comment: I like this answer for its simplicity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590317/disable-logging-for-one-container-in-docker-compose

Answer (score 3):

Note that Docker containers log to stdout and stderr for a reason. It allows a consistent log interface for commands like `docker logs` to use and for [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) to pick up information from containers. In a large container eco system, it's easier if everything works the same.

#### Runtime

At runtime there are a couple of options.

1. You can background the couchdb container and start the others in the foreground.

   ```
   docker-compose up -d couchdb
   docker-compose up other container names
   ```
2. You can start everything in the background, and only view the logs for particular containers

   ```
   docker-compose start  # or docker-compose up -d
   docker-compose logs -f other container names
   ```

#### Build time

To permanently modify logging you could change CouchDB's log config in an image build

```
couchdb:
  container_name: couchdb
  image: me/klaemo-couchdb:2.0.0
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.couchdb
  ports:
    - "5984:5984"
```

`Dockerfile.couchdb`

```
FROM klaemo/couchdb:2.0.0
COPY couchdb.ini /opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini
```

`couchdb.ini` needs to contain all the original config settings from the containers `/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini`, updating some the log settings from stderr to a file:

```
[log]
file = /opt/couchdb/log/couch.log
level = info
```

You can also set log levels specifically for a module

```
[log_level_by_module]
couch_httpd = info
couch_replicator = info
couch_query_servers = error
```

You probably want to mount the `/opt/couchdb/log` directory as a volume from the container host so you are not writing data into the current container instance all the time.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this from the compose file itself?

Comment: You could modify couchdb's [logging](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/logging.html) settings in an image build to output to a log file or suppress logging to a lower level. I'll add a note