# How to disable all docker containers JSON logs?

Tags: docker, docker-container, logrotate

I know about that there are **logrotate** and **clear** docker containers logs with this command: `truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`.

But is there any approach to disable all docker containers json-logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch to the `none` log driver, either as the default for all new containers, or on a per container basis. Documentation on logging drivers is here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers

To configure it as a daemon default for new containers, setup /etc/docker/daemon.json with:

```
{
  "log-driver": "none"
}
```

Or to run a single container without logging:

```
docker run --log-driver none ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Also I found a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34591999/3702377) for docker-compose